# Laravel 10 project jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a laravel 10 project, I am trying to use a jQuery plugin but get the error
**"jQuery is not defined"** from the plugin..

Without the plugin js included I get no errors and the jQuery function works.

In the blade I am using this , which works so jQuery is loading.

```
<script type="module">
var csrf_token = '{{csrf_token()}}';
var selectedAvatar = '';
$(function() {
    $('.avatar').click(function(event){
        selectedAvatar = event.target.getAttribute('data-avatar');
        selectedAvatar = selectedAvatar.replace('"','').trim();
        $('#avatar-large').attr("src","/uploads/avatars/"+selectedAvatar);
    });
});
```

In my app.js I have

```
import './bootstrap';

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.start();

import jQuery from 'jquery';
window.$ = jQuery;
```

and in my vite.config.js it looks like

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    laravel({
        input: [
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
        ],
        refresh: true,
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
        '$': 'jQuery'
    },
  }
});
```

But as soon as i add the

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/jsvendor/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
```

I get the Error

`Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Comment: Try `<script type="module">` instead of `<script type="text/javascript">`. IIRC, if you're using Vite for Laravel assets, it loads all the JS as modules, so other JS files that are dependent on these includes via Vite also need to be modules (and make sure you're importing this _after_ jQuery is imported via Vite)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused due scoping.
You can try in your app.js file, instead of assigning jQuery to window.$, use the `globalThis.$ = jQuery` syntax.
This makes jQuery available globally for all scripts, including your plugin.
this should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ending up being two things.

1. `<script type="module"> instead of <script type="text/javascript">`

thanks Tim Lewis

2. but i also had to change

   ```
   window.$ = jQuery;
   ```

to

```
   window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;
```